# How to find Screen Title from SAP Program Code and Screen Code?

Tags: abap

Is it possible to find SAP Screen title from SAP databases? I want to use the Program Code and Screen Code as input and would like to get the Screen Title. For example, the TCODE `VA01` Initial Screen `Screen Code - 0101` has a title `Create Sales Order: Initial Screen`. So I want to get the title text from the input `SAPMV45A 0101`.

I tried with table `TSTC`, Though it returns the TCODE Text in `TText` column, it not necessarily the page title always. Generally it changes in the subsequent pages.

As I don't have much experience with SAP, any piece of knowledge will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, there is no general way to do this for all possible programs. The title is set at runtime using the statements `SET TITLEBAR`, and you would have to evaluate the control (and as soon as conditional statements appear, also the data) flow of the application in order to determine the actual statement being executed (see [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) for more information about why this is a hard problem to solve). In many cases, this is even influenced by some settings or permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a GUI Title.

In SE80 (Sorry, German screenshot):
[image: SE80 with GUI-title]

The text itself is in table RSMPTEXTS:
[image]

To detect the right key (in your case A01), you must go to check the Coding.

Actually I can't give you a recipe to get the correct key,
but you may set a breakpoint (form CUA_SETZEN) and check the value/code yourself:
[image: Breakpoint]